# Windows XP: Computer cannot not found in the network

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking

I have a group network: COMPANY, so for every computer I click in computer, properties, than in computer name tab I change the work group, so I click in change to COMPANY.
So far this been working for every computer in the company, but one of them is not working.

Do you guys know why this is happening ?
This is so weird to me as for you guys. I know it sounds pretty crazy, but this is what´s happening here.

Comment: Check the sharing settings if the computer is discoverable.

Comment: Please be more specific about the issue than "not working". A screenshot or an exact error message often helps.

Comment: Are you saying you can't change this computer's workgroup (if so, what's the error) or are you saying that once you change it, its not being recognized by other comptuers on the network? And if so, can it see the other computers itself? Is it on the same router lan?

Comment: it was the last case @jdh, but now everything is fine. thanks.

Comment: @Bibhas: Oh my goodness, that was it! 2 hours of Googling and racking my brains... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I foun the solution for my problem, in properties of my connection the 'Client for Microsoft Network' was disable, I don't know why, but I enable it, then restart the computer, after that everyting works fine.

This link also help me: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic47775.html